# Is it a bug in NumberLinePlot?

Tags: plotting

```
NumberLinePlot[Sin[x] < Cos[x], {x, 0, 10 Pi}](*only 4 Intervals*)
```

[image]

```
Length@Reduce[Sin[x] < Cos[x] && 0 <= x <= 10 Pi, x](*got 6*)
```

Is it a bug in NumberLinePlot?

Comment: Definitely a bug - look at this:  `NumberLinePlot[Sin[x] < Cos[x], {x, 8 \[Pi], 10 Pi}]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way to get the plot you are looking for:

```
NumberLinePlot[Sin[x] < Cos[x] && 0 <= x <= 10 Pi, {x, 0, 10 Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: Cool! Thank you