# How to ask Mathematica to show NumberLinePlot of a function in logarithmic scale?

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

How to ask Mathematica to show  `NumberLinePlot`  of function $f(x)$ in a logarithmic scale? Adding `ScalingFunctions -> "Log"` or writing  `Log[f[x]]`do not work.

`NumberLinePlot[{f[x] < 0, f[x] >= 0}, {x, 0, 10}]`

Comment: `f[x_] := Exp[x - 5];
NumberLinePlot[{Log@f[x] < 0, Log@f[x] >= 0}, {x, 0, 10}]`

Comment: @cvgmt But this way it shows that your function is negative for $x<5$ which is not true.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an attemt with the `CustomTicks` package. You must first Import `CustomTicks.m`. First, some of the required functions:

```
logX[x_] := (
  v = x;
  If[x == 0, v = 0.001];
  If[v < 0, -Log10[-v], Log10[v]]
  )

f[x_] := Which[x < 0, y = 10^-x; myF[-y], x >= 0, y = 10^x; myF[y]]

Log10Ticks[p1_Integer, p2_Integer, spacing_, minorSubdivs_, top_] :=
 
   LinTicks[
          p1, p2, spacing, minorSubdivs,
   
   TickLabelFunction -> (Which[# < 
        0, (DisplayForm[SuperscriptBox[-10, IntegerPart[-#]]]), # >= 
        0, (DisplayForm[SuperscriptBox[10, IntegerPart[#]]])] &),
   MinorTickIndexTransformation -> (If[
       top, -Log10[# + spacing]*minorSubdivs, 
       Log10[# + spacing]*minorSubdivs] &),
   MajorTickStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.001]],
   TickRange -> (If[top, {-Infinity, 0}, {0, Infinity}]),
   ShowMinorTicks -> True
         ];
```

And this is how to call these functions with an example:

```
myF[x_] := x^3
NumberLinePlot[{-2000 < f[x] < 20, 100 < f[x] < 5000, 
  1000 < f[x] <= 30000000}, {x, logX[-100], logX[8]}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {Log10Ticks[-4, 6, 1, 9, False], 
    Log10Ticks[-4, 6, 1, 9, True]}}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
 ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> {-4, 6}]
```

The range of values for x in this example is from -100 to 8. These values must be wrapped in the `logX` function. The `myF` function is the function being studied. It is not called directly, but from the `logX` function.
Here is the result of this example:

[image]

Reversing the minor ticks for negative values only was problematic (I came very close, but it was still buggy), so I settled for showing the negative on the top of the frame.
This is `x^4`:

[image]

That was fun, but there is some cheating going on here, resulting from this "conversion" of log of a negative number to -log of a positive number. What is going on between 1 and -1? Is the first minor tick to the left of 10^0 corresponding to -2? I guess I fused together 10ˆ0 and -10ˆ0.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a manual way to do the scaling (you have to scale the domain and ticks one way and the input arguments the inverse way):

```
NumberLinePlot[
 {Sin[Pi*x] < 0, Sin[Pi*x] >= 0} /. x -> Exp@x // Evaluate, {x, Log@1, Log@7}, 
 Ticks -> {Charting`ScaledTicks["Log"], Automatic}]
```

[image]

*Update: The issue below is addressed in [is it a bug in NumberLinePlot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124831/is-it-a-bug-in-numberlineplot)*

Note the following seems to be a limitation (bug?) in `NumberLinePlot`. It doesn't locate all the intervals.  I noticed it using the OP's original plot domain.  I increased it to make the problem more obvious.

```
NumberLinePlot[{Sin[Pi*x] < 0}, {x, 0, 20}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could e.g. misuse ListLogLogPlot like:

```
f[x_] := Exp[x^2];
t = Table[{f[x], 1}, {x, 0, 10}];
ListLogLogPlot[t]
```

[image]